# Drag and Drop Only Animated GIFs and Preview them

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a box where i can drag an animated gif onto the page and then in a form box below it add tags so I can sent them via POST to the server via AJAX. I'm still learning javascript but I've misstepped somewhere Here is the code I'm fiddling with to do a preview when something is dropped on the box to show it in the holder div:

```
acceptedTypes = {
  'image/gif': true
},

function previewfile(file) {
     if ( acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (event) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = event.target.result;
  image.width = 250; // a fake resize
  holder.appendChild(image);
};
```

Here is a JSFiddle I'm JSStruggling with
http://jsfiddle.net/fightfirewithfire/mkLp6/1/

Comment: your jsfiddle appears to be empty

Comment: yes you were right @dav1dsm1th i totally botched that post, I fixed the link to a proper jsfiddle now :)